# How to keep columns in the output when grouping a data.table by several columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to "tidy" a large dataset, where multiple different types of data is merged in columns, and some data in column names. This is [a common scenario in biological dataset](http://varianceexplained.org/r/tidy-genomics/).

My data table has replicate measurements which I want to collapse into a mean. Converting the data into tidy format, these replicate values become additional rows. If I try to aggregate/group by several columns and calculate the mean of the replicates:

```
collapsed.data <- tidy.dt[, mean(expression, na.rm = T), by=list(Sequence.window,Gene.names,ratio,enrichment.type,condition)]
```

I get a resultant table that has only the columns used in `by` statement and followed with the `mean(expression)` as column `V1`. Is it possible to get all the other (unchanged) columns as well?

A minimalist example showing what I am trying to achieve is as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "c", "a"), b = rnorm(8), 
                 c = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2), d = rep('x', 8), e = rep('test', 8))
dt[, mean(b), by = list(a, c)]
#   a c         V1
#1: a 1 -0.7597186
#2: b 1 -0.3001626
#3: c 1 -0.6893773
#4: a 2 -0.1589146
```

As you can see the columns `d` and `e` are dropped.

Comment: you need to summarise them too. i.e something like `dt[,.(mean(b), head(d, 1), head(e, 1)), by=list(a,c)]`

Comment: This because data.table can't know which values for `d` and `e` you want to get, i.e., for each combination of `a` and `b` you can have multiple possible values in `d` and `e`. You need to be specific regarding which you want in return

Comment: Usually I add the columns I want to keep to the `by` argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is to include `d` and `e` in the grouping:

```
res <- dt[, mean(b), by = list(a, c, d, e)]
res
#   a c d    e         V1
#1: a 1 x test  0.9271986
#2: b 1 x test -0.3161799
#3: c 1 x test  1.3709635
#4: a 2 x test  0.1543337
```

If you want to keep *all* columns except the one you want to aggregrate, you can do this in a more programmatic way:

```
cols_to_group_by <- setdiff(colnames(dt), "b")
res <- dt[, mean(b), by = cols_to_group_by]
```

The result is the same as above.

By this, you have reduced the number of rows. If you want to keep all rows, you can add an additional column:

```
dt[, mean_b := mean(b), by = list(a, c)]
dt
#   a          b c d    e     mean_b
#1: a  1.1127632 1 x test  0.9271986
#2: a  0.7416341 1 x test  0.9271986
#3: b  0.9040880 1 x test -0.3161799
#4: b -1.5364479 1 x test -0.3161799
#5: c  1.9846982 1 x test  1.3709635
#6: a  0.2615139 2 x test  0.1543337
#7: c  0.7572287 1 x test  1.3709635
#8: a  0.0471535 2 x test  0.1543337
```

Here, `dt`is modified *by reference*, i.e., without copying all of `dt`, which might save time on large data.